# Difficulty in displaying data using repeater

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to display shopping categories with its sub categories and sub-sub categories using repeater.. Data is binding but it is not being displayed.. Can anyone help why?
here's my code:

**.aspx file**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="CategoryRepeater" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="CategoryRepeater_OnItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <a href='Clothing.aspx?CategoryId=<%#Eval("CategoryId") %>'<%#Eval("CategoryName") %>></a><br />
        <asp:Repeater ID="SubCategoryRepeater" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="SubCategoryRepeater_OnItemDataBound">
            <ItemTemplate>
                    <a href='Clothing.aspx?CategoryId=<%#Eval("CategoryId") %>&SubCategoryId=<%#Eval("SubCategoryId") %>'<%#Eval("SubCategoryName") %>></a><br />
                <asp:Repeater ID="SubSubCategoryRepeater" runat="server">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <a href='Clothing.aspx?CategoryId=<%#Eval("CategoryId") %>&SubCategoryId=<%#Eval("SubCategoryId") %>&SubSubCategoryId=<%#Eval("SubSubCategoryId") %>'<%#Eval("SubSubCategoryName") %>></a><br />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**C# Code:**

```
protected void CategoryRepeater_OnItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)||(e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem))
    {
        DataRowView dataItem = e.Item.DataItem as DataRowView;
        int categoryId = Convert.ToInt32(dataItem["CategoryId"]);
        Repeater rp = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("SubCategoryRepeater");
        ds = us.SelectSubCategories(categoryId);
        rp.DataSource = ds;
        rp.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void SubCategoryRepeater_OnItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)||(e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem))
    {
        DataRowView dataItem = e.Item.DataItem as DataRowView;
        int SubCategoryId = Convert.ToInt32(dataItem["SubCategoryId"]);
        Repeater rp1 = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("SubSubCategoryRepeater");
        ds1 = us.SelectSubSubCategories(SubCategoryId);
        rp1.DataSource = ds1;
        rp1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your source code to make sure nothing is being output to the page.  I think you just have the category name being rendered inside the anchor tag.

Here is the same code with the evals simplified to see what is going on

```
<a href='Clothing.aspx?CategoryId={catid}'{name}></a>
```

Should be:

```
<a href='Clothing.aspx?CategoryId={catid}'>{name}</a>
```

or

```
<a href='Clothing.aspx?CategoryId=<%#Eval("CategoryId") %>'><%#Eval("CategoryName") %></a>
```

Same mistake was done in all three locations.

Comment: Sorry, I posted at same time.  This should be correct answer, Manbir.

Answer (score 1):

I think everything is correct from the code, but your output is wrong.

You are doing this:

```
<a href='Clothing.aspx?CategoryId=<%#Eval("CategoryId") %>&SubCategoryId=<%#Eval("SubCategoryId") %>'<%#Eval("SubCategoryName") %>></a><br />
```

But it needs to be

```
<a href='Clothing.aspx?CategoryId=<%#Eval("CategoryId") %>&SubCategoryId=<%#Eval("SubCategoryId") %>'><%#Eval("SubCategoryName") %></a><br />
```

Noticed I moved the '>' back behind <%# Eval("SubCategoryName")%>